# Prove that there is no function $f$ that is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Prove that there is no function $f$ that is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and satisfies
$$|f(z)|\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}},\quad \operatorname{for all}\quad z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$$

I am studying for a final exam.  Not quite sure how to tackle this one.  I was thinking maybe use Maximum Modulus Theorem somehow?  Or Extended Liouville?  Should I define a new function $g=\sqrt{z}f(z)$?

Comment: $\sqrt(z) f(z)$ is a good idea, but is not analytic. $z/f(1/z)$, however, is. It is even holomorphic in the whole plane...

Answer (score 0):

Proof:

1. Note that the function $f$ has no zeros because of the given inequality.
2. Define a holomorphic function $g:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\to \mathbb{C}$ as
   $$ g(z)~:=~\frac{1}{zf(z)^2}.\tag{1}$$
3. Note that $|g|\leq 1$ is bounded because of the given inequality.
4. The function $g$ has a [removable singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) at $z=0$, cf. Riemann's theorem.
5. So the extension $\tilde{g}:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded entire function.
6. [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) then shows that $g=c$ is constant.
7. The constant $c\neq 0$ cannot be zero, cf. the definition (1) of $g$.
8. In other words, $$f(z)~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{cz}},\tag{2}$$
   which has a branch cut. Contradiction.